# Mongodb on Windows - How to delete records

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to find a solution for deleting a selection of records from my collection in MongoDB Compass for Windows.

Apparently Mongo Shell no longer exists for windows and I need to somehow do it through this Electron app?

I can do it through node but that's going to get old real fast.

Can someone confirm this and point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think mongo shell is available for Windows as well.

Comment: @itch96 There's nothing on their downloads page, just the compass app.

Comment: The `mongo` shell and other server command line tools (`mongodump`, `mongorestore`,  ...) are part of the Windows server installation. From the [MongoDB Download Center](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center) select "Community Server" and then "Windows".

Comment: @pguardiario, this video should help you out.  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-okpwPkEeg

Comment: @Stennie - Thanks, you're right - the client is installed with the "Community Server"

Answer (score 0):

[image: Compass]

As you will find, there is a dustbin button on the side of the document representation in Compass.
The image shows Compass v4.0.1.
Maybe you need to upgrade?

Comment: Yes I can delete them one at a time, but I want to delete an entire selection / query / whatever mongo calls it.

Answer (score 0):

To help anyone else, after installing "Community Server" I added "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin" to my PATH environment var and mow I can do 'mongo' from cmd.exe